# create dyanamic dropdown using Codeigniter form helper and get value from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

my array something like this

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Admin
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Manager
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => User
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [name] => Visitor
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 35
        [name] => gggggggggg
    )
```

)

and 
i am trying to create

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513493/dropdown-in-codeigniter-using-array-as-values

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($data as $row) {
                    $dropdownlist[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
                }
$insAttr = "class='form-control'";
echo form_dropdown("idDropdown", $dropdownlist, "", $insAttr);
```

Comment: please like the answer